# Unable to instantiate application, Unable to get package info, Package not installed?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Sometimes when I go to reboot my application to test, I am thrown a fatal excepton. Doesn't happen all the time and I'm testing through my device not an emulator, just as I always do. I'm not seeing a line where my code is erroring out so not sure what to do from here?

```
03-24 16:26:24.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1407): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
03-24 16:26:24.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1407): Process: com.jameswilson.fairbook, PID: 1407 
03-24 16:26:24.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1407): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.jameswilson.fairbook.FairBookApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for com.jameswilson.fairbook; is package not installed? 
03-24 16:26:24.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:516) 
03-24 16:26:24.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4317) 
03-24 16:26:24.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135) 
03-24 16:26:24.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
03-24 16:26:24.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
03-24 16:26:24.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 03-24 16:26:24.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
03-24 16:26:24.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
03-24 16:26:24.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
03-24 16:26:24.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
03-24 16:26:24.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 03-24 16:26:24.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
03-24 16:26:24.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1407): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for com.jameswilson.fairbook; is package not installed? 03-24 16:26:24.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):  at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:376) 
03-24 16:26:24.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:329) 
03-24 16:26:24.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:508) 
03-24 16:26:24.692: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: One does not "reboot" an application, so you are going to have to be more specific about what you mean.  What is triggering this attempt to start the application anyway?  Is the app installed in some odd way, such as on external storage?

Comment: App is being installed through Eclipse on the device itself. By reboot, I mean hit Run through Eclipse to reinstall the application.

Comment: I voted for this to be re-opened since the linked question is about an exception caused by a `NullReferenceException`, whereas this is caused by an `IllegalStateException`. I get the latter but not the former, and I'm not convinced they're the same problem.

Comment: Read this link .....  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426635/caused-by-java-lang-illegalstateexception-package-not-installed

Comment: Similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210695/unable-to-instantiate-application-unable-to-get-package-info