# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: package not installed?

Tags: java, android

```
06-26 05:07:17.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3231): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-26 05:07:17.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3231): Process: com.sample.calendar, PID: 3231
06-26 05:07:17.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3231): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for com.sample.calendar; is package not installed?
06-26 05:07:17.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3231):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:516)
06-26 05:07:17.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3231):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4317)
06-26 05:07:17.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3231):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-26 05:07:17.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3231):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
06-26 05:07:17.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3231):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-26 05:07:17.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3231):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-26 05:07:17.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3231):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-26 05:07:17.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3231):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-26 05:07:17.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3231):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-26 05:07:17.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3231):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-26 05:07:17.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3231):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-26 05:07:17.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3231):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-26 05:07:17.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3231): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for com.sample.calendar; is package not installed?
06-26 05:07:17.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3231):     at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:376)
06-26 05:07:17.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3231):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:329)
06-26 05:07:17.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3231):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:508)
06-26 05:07:17.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3231):     ... 11 more
```

I'm getting this kind of error in my logcat. Although I'm getting this error my project runs ok.So i just want to clarify these things regarding this error:

```
1.what causes this error?

2.what may happened if the error persist?

3.how to fix this error?
```

Comment: whats your application package name??

Comment: com.sample.calendar this is my package..i have the correct package and the emulator runs my project so i dont understand why im getting the error

Comment: pls check if you have specified the same package name in menifest file

Comment: delete the old apk (if any) from your device and then try running this project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to instantiate application, Unable to get package info, Package not installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613829/unable-to-instantiate-application-unable-to-get-package-info-package-not-insta)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this happens when you run the app from eclipse while you already have the previous version installed ? This won't happen if you uninstall the app before running it again from eclipse. Also, this won't cause any problems.

Comment: i see i will try uninstalling the app and be back on you..im just worried if it will affect the performance of my app because i see a lot of 
06-26 05:06:24.280: I/Choreographer(3193): Skipped 115 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

this line in my logcat..doing too much work thing

Comment: You also might want to do any time taking tasks such as network connection, database transactions, file transactions off the ui thread.

Comment: im sorry i dont understanding you..what do you mean by "do any time taking tasks such as network connection, database transactions, file transactions off the ui thread"?

Comment: in case you are doing any of the above mentioned tasks, do them on a background thread so that the ui is not blocked.

Comment: in connecting to database i am using databasehelper what i have there is a listview that is populated from the database..i read the link you showed and im studying it now..

Comment: So this reading from the database will take some time, minimal but it will and skipping frames could be caused by this. If you move the reading from database to a background thread, your problem of frames being skipped will mostly be solved :)

Comment: yep. You can fetch database values in doInBackground().

Comment: This problem causes a crash dialog to appear to the user when the app upgrades, so I think it is a bit of a problem.

Comment: Upgrading how ? Via the play store ?

Comment: Does this error appear in Crashlytics every time the project is compiled?

Answer (score 1):

Try using older gradle dependencies version in you `build.gradle` file. It helped me.

Use:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

Don't use:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
```

I find solution here - [Android Studio FloatingActionButton error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35675855/android-studio-floatingactionbutton-error)