# Android Studio cannot render FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, android-layout, google-app-engine, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

I'm just now learning how to develop in Android Studio and this error come up when I began my helloworld tutorial:

> Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated: - android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

The exception details are:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x1080029

I'm using version 23.2.0 of the Android Support Design library.

How can I get the FloatActionButton to render in the preview pane?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/knyFA.png]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the error stack trace generated by the previewer.  It says it cannot find a drawable resource by id 0x1080029.  Does a drawable exist by that ID? Are you supplying an invalid ID?  On my system it appears resources start at 0x7f010000.

Also found this:  [Android Studio FloatingActionButton error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35675855/android-studio-floatingactionbutton-error).  It says there could be a bug in version 23.2.0 of the support design lib and that downgrading to 23.1.0 fixes it.

Comment: I'm not sure what that ID means or stands for. So how would I change it?

Comment: The IDs are integers that are generated by android build tools based on the resources that you have in your project, and also by explicitly declared ids in `ids.xml` or implicitly declared id when you use `android:id="@+id/something"`.  The first thing I would do is make sure your `getDrawable` is using a valid drawable resource ID, in the form `R.drawable.some_name`.  The second thing would be to get Android Studio to regenerate the generated R files, and recompile the code to make sure `content_main.xml` is referring to the most up-to-date compiled code.

Comment: Added a comment in my answer - appears others are having the same issue.

Comment: Thank you!    So how would I downgrade to 23.2.0?

Comment: First open your `build.gradle` file. In Android Studio, you can quickly search by opening the search window by tapping `Shift` twice and typing build.gradle. In that file, I'm assuming you have a line like `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'`.  Just change that to 23.1.0, and Android Studio will sync the gradle config file the next time you try to compile (or will prompt you to do it now).

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to Android Support Library version 23.2.1 resolves the issue. It's already available in Android Studio SDK manager.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a bug in version 23.2.0 of the Android Support libraries; simply downgrading to 23.1.1 and rebuilding your project should make the problem disappear.

Note that the problem is not just in the Design library; also the AppCompat widgets cause problems for AppCompatButton and AppCompatImageButton also give similar errors reporting missing resources.