# The following classes could not be instantiated:- android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

Tags: android

Wasn't getting this error before but after doing some Android Studio updates I see the following error in my XML:

[image]

> The following classes could not be instantiated:
>           - android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>            Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find
>   resource ID #0x108003e   
>       at android.content.res.Resources.getResourceName(Resources.java:2235)   
>       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2602)
>     
>       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)   
>       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:806)   
>       at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:458)   
>       at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:26)
>     
>       at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:321)

It all has to do with that floating action button but I don't get what went wrong. I tried changing the API version in the top right but for some reason the other ones just show a blank screen.

EDIT: my grade:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
```

Comment: Define "did some updates"?

Comment: It's a missing resource, likely an internal support library resource. Did you try simply resyncing and cleaning your project?

Comment: @JHH I did try rebuilding the project and invalidating caches and restart. By "updates" I mean the SDK manager did all of the auto updates.

Answer (score 1):

Floating action Button is part of the android.support.design library, make sure you have that in the gradle dependencies.
If you have it, make sure to clean or rebuild the project.

```
dependencies{
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not including this earlier, but I found that some people had problems with the 23.2.0 versions, like in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35675855/android-studio-floatingactionbutton-error       I am not entirely sure this is the problem, but it is worth a try, since some people are reporting crashes and bugs with the newest build