# Can not use FloatingActionButton

Tags: android

I am doing the Android `first app` tutorial from http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html.

I am trying to use `FloatingActionButton` but it is not recognised by Android Studio.

I have added this import:

```
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
```

But it is also not found.

Do I need to add any other dependencies?

If I add `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'` to the module's `build.gradle` I get:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:design:23.2.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design/23.2.1/design-23.2.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design/23.2.1/design-23.2.1.jar
         file:/Users/octavian/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/23.2.1/design-23.2.1.pom
         file:/Users/octavian/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/23.2.1/design-23.2.1.jar
         file:/Users/octavian/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/design/23.2.1/design-23.2.1.pom
         file:/Users/octavian/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/design/23.2.1/design-23.2.1.jar
     Required by:
         MyFirstApp:app:unspecified
```

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio FloatingActionButton error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35675855/android-studio-floatingactionbutton-error)

Answer (score 0):

add your gradle Support Design Library

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
```

Comment: I get an error when adding the dependency. I updated my answer.

Comment: @octavian which gradle file are you adding this?

Comment: this one `Module: app`

Comment: @octavian so, if you update your question and add your gradle file, it will be more easier

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of them

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

Version 23.2 buggy . See details **[Android Studio FloatingActionButton error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35675855/android-studio-floatingactionbutton-error)**

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.+'
}
```